Translating Python for loops to Mathematica
I have the following snippet written in Python that I want to run in Mathematica
def squeezing(r, theta, cutoff, dtype=np.comple128):
    S = np.zeros((cutoff, cutoff), dtype=dtype)
    sqrt = np.sqrt(np.arange(cutoff, dtype=dtype))

    eitheta_tanhr = np.exp(1j * theta) * np.tanh(r)
    sechr = 1.0 / np.cosh(r)
    R = np.array(
        [
            [-eitheta_tanhr, sechr],
            [sechr, np.conj(eitheta_tanhr)],
        ]
    )

    S[0, 0] = np.sqrt(sechr)
    for m in range(2, cutoff, 2):
        S[m, 0] = sqrt[m - 1] / sqrt[m] * R[0, 0] * S[m - 2, 0]

    for m in range(0, cutoff):
        for n in range(1, cutoff):
            if (m + n) % 2 == 0:
                S[m, n] = (
                    sqrt[n - 1] / sqrt[n] * R[1, 1] * S[m, n - 2]
                    + sqrt[m] / sqrt[n] * R[0, 1] * S[m - 1, n - 1]
                )
    return S

Because Mathematica indexes its lists from 1, the translation is not verbatim. I tried doing the following
Squeezing[r_, theta_, cutoff_] := 
 Module[{S, sqrt, eithetaTanhr, sechr, R}, 
  S = ConstantArray[0, {cutoff, cutoff}];
  eithetaTanhr = Exp[I theta]*Tanh[r];
  sechr = Sech[r];
  R = {{-eithetaTanhr, sechr}, {sechr, Conjugate[eithetaTanhr]}};
  S[[1, 1]] = Sqrt[sechr];
  Do[S[[m, 1]] = Sqrt[m - 1]/Sqrt[m]*R[[1, 1]]*S[[m - 1, 1]], {m, 2, 
    cutoff - 1, 2}];
  Do[If[Mod[m + n, 2] == 0, 
    S[[m + 1, n + 1]] = 
     Sqrt[n - 1]/Sqrt[n]*R[[2, 2]]*S[[m + 1, n - 1]] + 
      Sqrt[m]/Sqrt[n]*R[[1, 2]]*S[[m, n]]], {n, 1, cutoff - 1}, {m, 0,
     cutoff - 1}];
  S]

But this does not work either. One problem is that the code calls S[[0,n]] in the second do loop and even though this comes with a Sqrt[0], Mathematica throws error. The second is that all the elements are not printed and some are just set equal to 0 which is how the array S was initialized. I would really appreciate some help regarding this.

Sqrt[0], Mathematica throws error  but Sqrt[0] is zero, and I see you have code which divides by Sqrt[n] which is Sqrt[n - 1]/Sqrt[n] so it could be due to this. I have not looked at your code in more details. Best way to translate code between languages, it not line by line. Better understand the algorithm in Python and what it is doing, and start new implementation from scratch in Mathematica.  There might even be one or two builtin functions in Mathematica which does all what the above Python code is doing. You could also try chatGPT, I read it is good in translating code now.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s too specific to be of much value, does not really allow us to provide guidance about wolfram language, and seems to boil down to a simple error.

@lericr sorry. Do you mind if I edit the question asking how to do recursions efficiently in Mathematica?

That sounds like a completely different question.

@lericr yeah, you can close this question. I'll ask another one if that's okay.

Here is a guess at a direct translation. The main point of difficulty was the negative index. It looks to me like we can always discard that term in that case, so I hacked in a workaround. Per @Nasser's comment, this direct translation is pretty ugly (from a Mathematica point of view), and you should actually start with the algorithm itself and encode it in Mathematica rather than translate from Python.
Squeezing[r_, theta_, cutoff_Integer] :=
  Module[
    {S = ConstantArray[0, {cutoff, cutoff}],
     sqrt = Sqrt[Range[0, cutoff - 1]],
     eithetaTanhr = Exp[I theta]*Tanh[r],
     sechr = Sech[r],
     R}, 
    R = {{-eithetaTanhr, sechr}, {sechr, Conjugate[eithetaTanhr]}};
    S[[1, 1]] = Sqrt[sechr];
    Do[
      S[[m + 1, 1]] = Sqrt[m - 1]/Sqrt[m]*R[[1, 1]]*S[[m - 1, 1]],
      {m, 2, cutoff - 1, 2}];
    Do[
      Do[
        If[
          Divisible[m + n, 2], 
          S[[m + 1, n + 1]] = 
            Sqrt[n - 1]/Sqrt[n]*R[[2, 2]]*S[[m + 1, n - 1]] + 
            If[0 != m, Sqrt[m]/Sqrt[n]*R[[1, 2]]*S[[m, n]], 0]],
        {n, 1, cutoff - 1}],
      {m, 0, cutoff - 1}];
    S]

